# Why am I getting different p-values out of a z-table than the ones described in my textbook?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, proportion

I am reading Sharpe, Business Statistics and at chapter 10 I encountered P-values.

The following definition is given: "The P-value tells us the probability of observing a value that extreme, **or even more extreme**." (Given the null hypothesis is true)

They then work out an example that uses a one-proportion z-test that ends up using a Z-value of 3.24. They calculate the probability and then claim that "The probability of observing a sample proportion 3.24 **or more** standard deviations above the mean of a Normal Model is < 0.001.

However, when I look up the P-value corresponding to z = 3.24 I get a different value than 0.001; 0.9994 What I don't understand is why they say that the P-value is the probability of observing a a value that extreme **or more extreme**, but then use the inverse (1 - 0.9994 = < 0.001) and claim that this inverse is actually is the chance of observing a value as extreme or **more extreme.**

What is the fault in my reasoning or use of the z-table, and what is the hidden knowledge they are using to switch between definitions like that?

Comment: `when I look up the P-value corresponding to z = 3.24 I get the inverse of 0.001; 0.999` - How exactly do you "look [it] up"?

Comment: I used a a table. I'll update my question to give the appropriate value, I wrote it out of memory.

Comment: Please describe it in more detail. What table? Etc.

Comment: I don't know what to describe in more detail. My question isn't about the table I used.

Comment: Read the fine print, most tables tell you if the returned number is area under the observed z or above the observed z, see the top illustration of this image: https://faculty.elgin.edu/dkernler/statistics/ch07/images/z-table.gif.

Comment: Curses! It says "Areas under the standard Normal curve." on the page. I feel like a fool now. Thanks Penguin_Knight, I guess that solved it.

Comment: Well, p-value corresponding to z=3.24 is 0.001 and not 0.999. Ergo you looked it up *wrong*. That's why I was asking about the details.

Comment: I will revise the original question and title to make it clear that I am getting Z-Values that aren't in line with what the book is explaining.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They were using a two-tailed test in that situation.  As a result, "as extreme or more extreme" means *either further above or further below*.  When you looked up the p-value on a $z$-table, you were looking at a one-tailed (almost certainly left tailed) $p$-value.  That is the way $z$-tables are constructed by convention.  If your table didn't include a two-tailed $p$ (which would be less common), you can compute it by multiplying the $p$-value by $2$, if $<.5$, or multiplying the complement ($1-p$) by $2$, if $>.5$.  (You can click the image for a larger version.)

[image: z table]

Comment: If you would incorporate Penguin_Knight's comment on my question I'll accept the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @Zimano, that's what I meant by "to the left". Note that all refer to proportions of the total area 'under' the curve in some sense, it's just a question of whether it is the area to the right of the mark or to the left (or to the right of the lower mark plus to the left of the corresponding upper mark, for a 2-tailed p).

Comment: Yes, gung beat me to the answer.  There are really three meaning to more extreme, one-sided below, one-sided above and two-sided.  What you use is determined by the form of the hypothesis test.  If you are only interested in alternatives where the test parameter is lower than the null value you use the use one-sided low..If you are interested only in high values  of the parameter use the upper one-sided p-value.  If you are interested in differences on both sides you use the two-sided p-value.